# Broadcast ICMP and gratuitous ARP

Tags: arp, broadcast, icmp

When sending an ICMP broadcast, all nodes can respond. **is it the case of the sender too?**

If it's the case then:

Is it specified somewhere that the sender should respond with gratuitous ARP when the sender receives the ICMP packet sent using his own IP address (IP conflict)?

[image]

Comment: No, why would the sender respond to it's own request?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

Since a broadcast is flooded to all nodes *but the sending one*, the sender doesn't receive the broadcast and cannot respond.

Note that the only ICMP message anyone can respond to is an *ICMP echo request* which won't usually be sent as a broadcast. Duplicate address detection (DAD) uses ARP and doesn't rely on ICMP echo.

It *is* possible though that the recipient, seeing its own IP address on a received packet, sends out a GARP to participate in DAD.

The proposed [RFC 5227](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5227) might be of interest to you.